# How to use validation names and attributes while using custom validator resolver [laravel 6]

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I added a custom validation errors using `Validator::resolver()` as bellow :

```php
class Rest extends Validator
{
    public function addFailure($attribute, $rule, $parameters = [])
    {
        $message = $this->getMessage($attribute, $rule);

        $message = $this->makeReplacements($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters);

        $customMessage = new MessageBag();

        $customMessage->merge(['code' => strtolower($rule.'_rule_error')]);
        $customMessage->merge(['message' => $message]);

        $this->messages->add($attribute, $customMessage);
    }

}
```

and i called it using resolver in `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new Rest($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

and while trying to change an attribute name it doesn't work:

```php
$request->validate(
[
    'group_id'      => 'required'
], [], 
[
    'group_id'      => 'the lesson group'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usualy extend the validator when the provider is registering

Eg.:

```
Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   return $value == 'foo';
});
```

Remmeber you need to return true or false.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#using-extensions